# Alpha-beta pruning with ties causes avoidable loss

Tags: algorithm, recursion, search, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

In developing software to play some simple strategy games, I am using standard techniques for searching and evaluation, including alpha-beta pruning. But I have encountered an unexpected problem which results in one player choosing an ultimately losing move instead of one that ties the game.

Imagine this scenario: The MAX player has at least two moves to evaluate at depth D. One results in a tie, so its value is 0 and alpha is set to 0. In searching a second MAX move, with alpha = 0, at depth D+1, MIN has at least two replies to evaluate. One of them is a forced win for MIN. An earlier MIN reply results in a tie, so its value is 0, and beta is set to 0. This triggers an alpha-beta cutoff for MIN because beta 0 <= alpha 0. So the later forced win for MIN is never seen, and that second MAX move gets a value of 0. Thus it may be chosen instead of the first MAX move (a tie), resulting in an avoidable loss for MAX.

Here's a more concrete example: A tic-tac-toe board can be represented as…

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Let's say that the MIN player chooses square 8. The MAX player has eight possible replies. The first four replies examined – squares 0, 1, 2, and 3 – are all evaluated to eventually result in a loss for MAX. Square 4 is evaluated as a tie, with a value of 0, and thus alpha is set to 0. Square 5 is next evaluated, and as part of that process, the alpha value of 0 is passed down, and the possible replies by MIN are evaluated one at a time. Square 0 is evaluated for MIN as a tie, and thus beta is set to 0. The next possible reply by MIN, square 1, is also a tie. At this point, both beta and alpha are 0, triggering an alpha-beta pruning of the remaining MIN replies. These include squares 4, 6, and 7, all of which allow MIN to win. But these are never seen, because of the alpha-beta pruning. A value of 0 is passed up the search tree. Consequently, MAX incorrectly sees square 5 as a tie just as good as square 4, even though playing at square 5 would likely result in a loss.

Does anyone see a problem with this analysis? Isn't this a problem with alpha-beta pruning?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but if you're suggesting that alpha-beta causes the min-max to fail, that's wrong. Alpha-beta pruning is a strict and free optimization that trims branches that have no chance of influencing the outcome and don't need to be visited. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning): "When applied to a standard minimax tree, it returns the same move as minimax would, but prunes away branches that cannot possibly influence the final decision."

Comment: I understand pruning should not change the outcome, but in this scenario, in which pruning is properly applied (unless I'm doing something wrong, which is possible), it does appear to change the outcome. Specifically, if pruning is disabled, then when the second MAX move is evaluated, it will always be rejected because the forced loss to MIN will be detected, and the first move (a tie) will always be preferred over the losing move. But if pruning is in force, then the second MAX move will be evaluated as a tie, and could be chosen because it appears to be just as good as the first one.

Comment: I of course am not _trying_ to evaluate losing moves as ties, but that is the unintended result in the scenario outlined. The beta cutoff occurs when evaluating the second MIN reply to the second MAX possible move, which causes the MIN forced win to be discarded, making that second MAX move look like a tie when in fact it isn't. Anyway, I'm not going to repeat the original post here. What part of the original post is not clear?

Comment: But at depth D+1, you're the minimizing player, MIN, not the maximizing player. Alpha was passed down as 0. Beta is initially a huge positive number. The first MIN move is a tie, so beta is set to 0. That's what triggers the cut-off. It sounds like you're thinking this is happening at depth D; it's not.

Comment: But MAX does not learn that the second move is a losing one because the losing path is pruned as a result of beta, and thus that second move is evaluated as a tie. That's the whole point. It might be helpful if you stepped through the evaluation and pruning process as described in the original post, and not assume that MAX has a view of the entire search tree, but instead only sees what is left after alpha-beta pruning.

Comment: Anyway, I think I'm just adding confusion, so I'll self-destruct my side of the thread soon to clean it up.

Comment: No need to nuke anything from orbit. ;-)  Thanks for taking the time to reply.